# KineticJS Works in Jsfiddle, not on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

I tried a simple KineticJS example hosted on my own server, and I have a problem placing the 4 handles at the 4 corners of the Image. The handle points will be at the wrong position, as shown in the screencap below. However the handles are position correctly in the jsfiddle!

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NPB77/

[image]

I'm very new to KineticJS, will really appreciate if I can be pointed in the right direction, thank you!

---

### Update

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/NPB77/1/

Solved by placing `addAnchor` within the `imageObj.onload()` function.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var thing = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: imageObj
    });

    addAnchor(thingGroup, 0, 0, "topLeft");
    addAnchor(thingGroup, imageObj.width, 0, "topRight");
    addAnchor(thingGroup, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, "bottomRight");
    addAnchor(thingGroup, 0, imageObj.height, "bottomLeft");

    thingGroup.add(thing);
    stage.draw();
};

imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

However, now when I drag the corner handles which is supposed to rescale the image, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setPosition' of undefined
```

What went wrong here? I dont understand why `group.get(".topLeft")` is not working, is this a scope problem?

Comment: A link to your website would be helpful.

Comment: @Blender Right now its a locally hosted LAMP setup.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Nope no errors in Chrome dev tools. Exact same code as in jsfiddle

Comment: My suspect is that in the locally hosted page, `imageObj.width` is still undefined when `addAnchor(thingGroup, imageObj.width, 0, "topRight");` is called. However I'm not familiar enough with KineticJS to wait for `imageObj` to finish loading before calling `addAnchor`.

Comment: @Blender I managed to get the handles to position properly (updated original post). However I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setPosition' of undefined` when I try to move one of the handles to rescale the image.. any ideas?

Comment: The only difference should be that jsFiddle calls all of your code when the body loads. Your error seems to be saying that whatever element you're trying to call `setPosition` on doesn't exist yet, so can you make sure that your code doesn't access any elements outside of a `$(document).ready()` callback (try wrapping all of your code in one and see if that fixes it)?

Comment: Please keep in mind I only started looking at KinecticJS a few minutes ago, but how about adding an id to the image and then reference that ... http://jsfiddle.net/NPB77/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create `thing` in your `initStage` function give it an id that you can reference later.
So it looks like this...

```
var thing = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    id: "thingImage"
});
```

..then in your `update` function you can reference it like this...

```
var image = group.get("#thingImage")[0];
```

Here's a working example...
http://jsfiddle.net/NPB77/2/